# Why does Windows Update fail with code 80072F8F?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I installed a Windows 7 Enterprise on a Virtual Machine (Microsoft Virtual Server 2005). The Windows is activated.

The first thing I found was [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Windows-Update-error-80072f8f), but I am definitely sure my timezone and time and date information is correct.

Still I get a Code 80072F8F Windows Update encountered an unknown error. When trying to "Check for updates".

I know about [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929458) from Microsoft. I also know about [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/44569/windows-update-error-code-80072f8f-possibly-datetime-not-correct-but-it-is) on ServerFault. I tried everything there to no avail.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem might be that the Microsoft Windows Update web server SSL cert is untrusted due to a missing root certification authority (CA) certificate.

See this article: [Windows root certificate program members](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931125)
where you can manually download and install all third-party root certificates that are distributed via the Windows Root Certificate Program.

Comment: Ok, that did the trick. Although the article you link to doesn't apply to Windows 7, after installing the root certificate update, Windows Update started working again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was the time on the server was not correct. After enabling syncing with an Internet Time service under the clock settings, I was able to run windows update normally.